# How to link to contents of git repo while switching between branches

Tags: git, ln

I would like to create links to files within a git repo. When I make changes to separate branches, changes are not reflected in the linked file. Is there any way to make links within a git repo (without having to make links for each branch)?

Comment: Are you trying to use hardlinks or symlinks?  Can you give an example of the commands you're using to do this as a code block?

Answer (score 2):

When `git checkout` needs to replace a work-tree file, it calls `unlink` first, then `open(O_CREAT)`.  This means that if you make a hard link from some existing work-tree file to some path name that exists outside the work-tree, the hard link is broken whenever Git itself replaces the work-tree copy of the file.

There is no flag to avoid this behavior.

(Making hard links *within* the Git repository—from some existing work-tree file to some new work-tree file—behaves similarly, in that Git will consider these to be two different files.  If you `git add` the second name and commit, you have made two different names for the same content, but Git won't hard-link the two files together later.)

In general, if you make a *symbolic* link outside your work-tree (or even inside it!) to a file that may or may not exist *in* your work-tree, that will work fine: the symbolic link will continue to contain the name of the file that may or may not exist in your work-tree, regardless of which version of that file you check out (or don't check out) from any given commit.